# jQuery: How to modify variable inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete function that I use to help me add keywords faster when inserting rows into database. Inside function I have a variable in which I have stored all keywords used for suggestions. After a row is inserted to database, with AJAX I get all keywords from database including keyword from the row I just added.

The problem is that I want to modify the variable in which are stored the old keywords by adding the keywords I just got from database with AJAX.

Here is the code:

```
var autocompleteKeywords = [ 'keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3' ];

// Autocomplete tags
$('#search_keyword').autocomplete({
    maxHeight: 400,
    width: 200,
    lookup: autocompleteKeywords
});
```

The variable I want to modify with the new keywords I got with AJAX is `autocompleteKeywords`.

Here is the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_actions.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: { action: "select_keywords" },
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    
    success: function(result)
    {
        autocompleteKeywords = result.keywords;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please note that autocompleteKeywords isn't a variable, it is an array literal.

Comment: or possibly a variable which is instantiated with a reference to an array literal :), possibly depending on what javascript engine it is run, and when you are doing the describing :)

Comment: @EricHerlitz I know, I wanted to say that I want the current array with keywords to be replaced with the other updated array with keywords that I get with AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to handle the datasource yourself, there is an optition of jQuery UI Autocomplete that meet your need:

Have a look: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

```
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
      }
    });
```

or here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
            value: item.name
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
      "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
      "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
  },
  open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
  },
  close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
  }
});
```

Comment: From beginning I like to get all keywords from db and let the plugin choose the suggestions from the list. I think it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your description you want to add the keywords coming from the database

The best way in my opinon is to concatenate the default array with the incoming values from the database

```
success: function(result) {
    autocompleteKeywords = [].concat(autocompleteKeywords, result.keywords)
}
```

Comment: I want to replace the current array with the one I get from AJAX, that is updated with keywords from the row that was added.

Comment: The problem is that the array remains the same, no change. The new array with new keywords is not added. I think that it needs something like a "reset"?